# summary dataframe with loop in R

Tags: r, loops, summary

I have three dataframe: `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`
I want to use see summary of each dataframe, instead of using

```
summary(AAA)
summary(BBB)
summary(CCC)
```

I wonder if I can use loop to solve this function, I tried the following lines, but didn' work

```
tables = list('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')
for (table in tables){
  summary(table)
}
```

Comment: You should change `list('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')` to `list(AAA, BBB, CCC)`; note that I removed the quotes. You also need to call `print` explicitly if you want to print the output (`print(summary(table))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a for loop necessarily, e.g.

```
tables = list(mtcars, mtcars)
purrr::map(tables, summary)

lapply(tables, summary)
```